# CORS AWS using Lambda (JAVA)

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-lambda

I am using AWS API Gateway with a Java Lambda Backend. 
Everything is peachy until a friend using Angular 4 is trying to make requests. He keeps getting:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at URL (Reason: CORS header
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

I have enabled CORS via the gateway:

[image: AWS image]

Despite this the error remains. What should I modify ?

Thanks.

Ian's Comments:
I use Output/Input Streams so my output, as per your comment I am trying as below but still no success. Any ideas ?

```
private void sendResponse(JSONObject body, int statusCode, OutputStream outputStream)
{   
    OutputStreamWriter writer;                                                             
    JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(); 
    JSONObject responseHeadersJson = new JSONObject();
    responseHeadersJson.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    responseHeadersJson.put("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type");

    responseJson.put("headers",responseHeadersJson);
    responseJson.put("statusCode", statusCode);
    responseJson.put("body", body.toJSONString());          
    try {
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
        writer.write(responseJson.toJSONString());  
        writer.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Outputstream Error "+e);
    }}
```

Comment: Can you verify the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' exists and is exactly equal to the one you set: '*' ? I believe you should test this with https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Can also just check in the chrome network panel or do a curl request and see the response headers for the request.  Also this isn't angular specific it's an issue with JS doing an AJAX call in a browser across domains the browser does the OPTIONS request automatically ahead of any POST or GET request to get the header information if it doesn't have the cross origin headers set then the request is denied.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that you are using Proxy Resource.

That means you are controlling the response thats going back as well from your Lambda. CORS needs to be configured on the response as well by adding the origin header.

When you build the response you need to add the cors headers by passing the domain or *.

I have built a ResponseBuilder that you can use as an example:

https://github.com/ahpoi/commons-utils-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ahpoi/commons/utils/aws/lambda/model/proxy/response/ResponseBuilder.java

```
public ResponseBuilder originHeader(String domain) {
    headers.put(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, domain);
    return this;
}

private void initDefaultHeaders() {
    headers.put(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "Content-Type");
}

public Response build() {
    this.initDefaultHeaders();
    return new Response(statusCode, headers, body);
}
```

If you didn't use Proxy Resource, your configuration would have been enough.

Comment: Edited the question with some additions from your comments but still no effect.

Comment: Thanks. I had made a boo boo  where the /auth was not set to CORS so i guess everything after didnt work either. Thank you for the help.